# How to send Email from a SQL Job with results of multiple select statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, sql-server-agent

I want to create a SQL job and send an emails with multiple select statements including in query results. Is it possible with SQL Job or should I use SSIS?

**Edit 1:**

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',  
    @recipients = '****@abc.com', 
    @Execute_query_database = 'AdventureWorks',
    @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks.Production.WorkOrder  
                  WHERE DueDate > '2018-03-30'  
                  AND  DATEDIFF(dd, '2004-04-30', DueDate) < 2
              SELECT * FROM NorthWind.Production.Work  
                  WHERE DueDate > '2018-04-30'  
                  ' ,  
    @subject = 'Work Order Count',  
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

> Error message: File attachment or query results size exceeds allowable
>   value of 1000000 bytes.

**Edit 2**: I feel that SQL agent job not pointing to desired DB and sp_send_email has no database name. so I added `@Execute_query_database = 'AdventureWorks'` but still there is no improvement because in SQL SELECTS using two different databases.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your results are too big, and you re hitting the limit set up in your database mail. You can up it, probably.

Comment: @James I changed to 2000000, but still ended up with same error. Actually I am trying to pull >10MB data

Comment: I've updated my answer below to reflect your edits

Comment: What person on earth wants an e-mail attachment this big?

Comment: @AaronBertrand.. who said NO to receive an email attachments size from 1KB to 10MB.  any restrictions in SQL server?

Comment: Took me 5 seconds to Google the answer: http://bfy.tw/HU4t leading me to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997628/how-do-i-increase-the-maximum-allowed-attachment-size-for-email-sent-using-msdb

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Thanks. I have tried this, not helpful. FYI, everyone good at googling not only you.

Answer (score 6):

You are basically sending 1GB file from sql server which is max. You can reconfigure the default using

> exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'MaxFileSize','2000000'-- 2GB

I would say, use bcp out the file, compress it using zip or 7zip and then send using powershell or ssis.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed Maxfilesize but still it throws same error. I thought of using compression and send through power shell.

Comment: Does your mail server have size limit ?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question it is possible to have many select statements in your query, I am not aware of a limit on the number.

Your first query would execute without any issue but your second query is creating a result set bigger than your settings allow so it will not send, I agree with @kin that you would be better off saving the results down somewhere and then email a link. As a bonus your network administrators will be happier too!

Answer (score 2):

Terminate your T-SQL statements appropriately in your @query parameter with a semicolon and you'll get both result sets in your attachment (assuming that the result sets are smaller than your attachment limit size). You'll also need to escape your date values.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',  
    @recipients = '****@abc.com', 
    @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM AdventureWorks.Production.WorkOrder  
              WHERE DueDate > ''2018-03-30''  
              AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2;
              SELECT * FROM NorthWind.Production.Work  
              WHERE DueDate > ''2018-04-30'';' ,  
    @subject = 'Work Order Count',  
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```